# Change Button Text on Button Click Infinite times

Tags: android, button, text, click

I want to change the text on a button infinitely many times. i.e. It should say "1" when clicked once and so on.

Can I get a relevant code? I am fresh to Android Programming.
Thanks

Comment: Please be clear of what you want to achieve.

Comment: you can increase your number in onClick() method and set to text of your button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish what you want, `globally` declare an `integer` with a value 0. And inside `onClick` of `button` increment the value of `integer` and set that as `text` to `button`.

Sample Code:

**Globally declare:**

```
int count = 0;
```

**Inside onCreate():**

```
           button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                  count++;
                  button.setText(""+count);

            }
        });
```

Comment: how do i declare a global variable?

Comment: @user3086548 just declare it above onCreate();

Comment: thanks. how can i add glow animation on click to it?

Comment: @user3086548 glow animation? do you want the button to be highlighted when clicked?

Comment: yes exactly. Do I need to learn animation for it or can it be done using xmls itslef?

Comment: @user3086548 http://android-holo-colors.com/ go through the link. choose your desired color and toggle the switch to yes near button option. then you download the zip file. copy and paste the contents of the different folders inside respective folders in your project.then you run and check your project. you can see the difference.

Comment: Do I need to make changes in code or is it by default that they highlight on pressing? Because just copy pasting them into resources isn't making a difference.

Comment: @user3086548 sorry forgot to mention. In your xml just add the following line for your button. `android:background="@drawable/btn_default_holo_light"`